# The validation file can not find the form data

Tags: php

I've made two files php, one of the has the validation php code and another has the form where I input some data, but looks something is wrong with Switch command, look many time to find the problem but unfortunately I did not get true.

Here is my code;

**First file where I've FORM**

```
<form action="Validation_search_02.php" method="post">

<label>Your favourite fruit:<input type="text" name="t_Opst" id="t_Opst"></label>
<input type="submit" name="G_mby" id="G_mby">
</form>
```

**The second file where I've the validation file(php)**

```
<?php

if(isset($_P0ST["G_mby"])){

$L_ings=$_POST["t_Opst"];

switch($L_ings){

case "Apple":

 echo "Your favourite fruit is $L_ings";
break;

case "Pear":


echo "Your favourite fruit is $L_ings";
break;

case "Banana":

 echo "Your favourite fruit is $L_ings";
break;

case "Mango":


 echo "Your favourite fruit is $L_ings";
break;

default:

echo "You should eat some fruit";

}
}
?>
```

Comment: And what is __wrong__ here?

Comment: Which *exact* value are you entering in the input? Your question is unclear.

Comment: ok. the value i inter is the name of fruit; apple. pear,.. and when I click in submit button I get just bank browser.

Comment: `Apple` and `apple` are two different animals, as are `Pear` and `pear`.

Comment: `$L_ings=$_POST["G_mby"];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your php file you can verify if there is a POST request, when it comes to your code there is no need for a switch because there is a repetition of the same code several times, you can use an if and or clauses instead. Try this:

```
<?php

  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    $L_ings = $_POST["t_Opst"];

    echo "hola";

    if($L_ings == "Pear" or $L_ings == "Banana" or $L_ings == "Mango" or $L_ings == "Apple")
         echo "Your favourite fruit is $L_ings";
    else
         echo "You should eat some fruit";
  }

?>
```

Comment: There is a FORM with input text and Submit button, after intruded the data like, Apple, Birne and son on than clicking on the Submit must display with echo the result.

That's the idea and just practicing diferente why to get the result with Switch/case.

Comment: I found the solution for my problem, the only things was, just replaced ;"if(isset($_P0ST["G_mby"]))" , with "if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")", the first one($_SERVER)look works with Switch/case and the second one just "if , if/else" but not with Switch/case.

Comment: I've already mentioned that you should verify if there is a POST request for the ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"), for the switch/case i don't find the interest to use it in this example because there is basically two echos one that prints the result and the name of the fruit  and the other prints ' "You should eat some fruit" ' so why use a switch/case, there is a repetition in your code, if you are practicing on an example of switch/case instruction then this is a bad example.